# How to run docker container with -i -t options using TeamCity?

Tags: teamcity, docker

I'm trying to run docker container as part of a build on linux TeamCity build agent. However, if I run docker container with `-i -t` options, there is no output in the Build Log from executed command.

Command Line build step:

```
sudo docker run -i -t --name="echo_test" ubuntu echo "test"
```

Build Log missing output from echo command:

```
Step 1/2: Command Line (1s)
   [Step 1/2] Starting: /home/ec2-user/BuildAgent/temp/agentTmp/custom_script6340936320796175009
   [Step 1/2] in directory: /home/ec2-user/BuildAgent/work/831248796cfa0a04
   [Step 1/2] Process exited with code 0
```

Docker container logs do have the output from echo command:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-28-218-103 ~]$ docker logs echo_test
test
```

Could someone explain why this is happening or provide some way to diagnose the issue?

If I change `run docker` options to either: just `-i`, just `-t`, or remove them both it works.

It's worth mentioning that at first I was getting `sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo` error when trying to execute sudo commands in Command Line build step in TeamCity. I commented out `Default requiretty` in `/etc/sudoers` to solve this.

---

I got echo to output text to Build Log by adding `-a stdout -a stderr` options.

Command Line build step:

```
sudo docker run -i -t -a stdout -a stderr --name="echo_test" ubuntu echo "test"
```

So the question is now why they were not required when executing command on local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the key information here is the error you were receiving while using sudo.

```
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

When you have a tty the stdin and stdout handles, for devices and drivers, are connected for you. But since the build does not have a tty, they are not connected for you. By attaching stdin and stdout in the run command, you connected them yourself.

When you ran the docker command locally, you ran it with a tty and the handles were connected for you by default.